# What is known, in principle, about the possibility of approximating the random discrepancy between a statistical estimate and its parameter?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, information-theory, approximation, point-estimation

The difference between the value of a statistical estimate and its parameter's value is almost never exactly $0$. For example, $r - \rho$, for a unique sample $r$, is likely to be some non-zero magnitude with positive or negative sign. This would be true even in the (purely theoretical) case of unbiased and error-free measurement. A random quantity (call it $\epsilon_{r}$), due solely to sampling error, would still leave $r$ above or below $\rho$. This is a weird and mostly theoretical quantity, not directly observable but also not a parameter. Yet, it is a concept integral to estimation theory, and we can even conceive of it arising in a couple of multi-sample estimation contexts, like meta-analysis and survey sampling.

Consider that a meta-analytic estimate will in the long run be more accurate than any of the individual study effect estimates from which it's computed, because errors of all kinds will cancel. If all measures across all studies were taken using the exact same instrument, the measurement errors may not cancel, but the random errors should. So, the difference between one of those independent estimates and the meta-estimate of the effect approximates $\epsilon$ for the individual estimate. Likewise, if a survey or test is administered to a random sample that is, by chance, nonetheless demographically unrepresentative of the population, reweighting the responses consistent with parameters measured in a prior census is expected to yield an estimate closer to the parameter. Again, the difference between the original estimate and the estimate on reweighted data approximates $\epsilon$.

It would be extremely useful if one could approximate the random discrepancy $\epsilon$ for an isolated point estimate, that is, from a single sample and without incorporating a priori information. We could report, for example, that $r = .3$ and $r − \rho \approx −.08$. The fact that this is not done implies that it is not doable, but I've struggled to find an actual statement to that effect, much less a formal argument. I have found several texts I can cite to the effect that a variable like this couldn't be a statistic, nor could its information be Fisher information, given that $\epsilon$ is not a parameter (it's uniquely defined for each sample). The approximation question is crucially different since its answer would have to account for all types of information, including entropy and algorithmic information (complexity).

My question is: Is there a proof, theorem, axiom, conjecture, etc., that formally addresses whether or not $\epsilon$, as defined above, can be constructed? Based on my not finding anything after extensive searching of the statistics literature, I think it would be most likely to appear under another paradigm, like information theory or pure mathematics (probability or combinatorics, perhaps).

Comment: This sounds like *every* solution to a statistical inference problem.  Standard errors, margins of error, confidence intervals, and variances of the sample statistics are all nearly equivalent ways of estimating error.  If you wish to remove measurement error, then you need data that permit estimating that measurement error.  Otherwise there's little you can do beyond including all forms of observational error in these quantities.  This question looks too broad, then, to be answerable in our format.  Do you have a specific problem you wish to apply these ideas to? Could you state it?

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about what you mean by "a variable" in "a variable approximating the estimate's random discrepancy with its parameter." Estimates of _distributions_ of those discrepancies underlie statistical inference in general, as another comment notes.

Comment: This is a question about theory, not an estimation problem. To clarify: "Discrepancy between estimate and parameter"=their arithmetic difference with a sign, not a variance. "Independent of measurement error"=arises solely from sampling error so is truly independent. "Variable"=a function of data with many possible values. "Approximate"=quantify from incomplete information, not infer or estimate, which is only possible for parameters. Most would agree this is impossible, but I'd like to cite someone saying it, preferably supported at least by a syllogism or tautology. I'll edit to clarify.